# call python script and store return value in perl

Tags: python, python-2.7, perl

I have a perl script in which I am calling python script through system command which is in some another location.

Perl script part where it calls python script

```
$path=system("C:\\FindPath\\find_path_location.py", $ID);
print $path;
```

The python script takes the argument $ID, does some processing and generate a path which is stored in variable path1. I want to use the value of "path1" in my perl script

find_path_location.py

```
def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    *function execution*
    path1 = *some path which is generated*
    print "{0}".format(path1)
    return path1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()

    try :
        main()
    except Exception as e :
         print >> sys.stderr, "Error: " + str(type(e))
         traceback.print_exc()
    finally :
         endTime = time.time()
    print "Total Time: " + str(round((endTime - startTime), 2)) + " Seconds"
    print "Done."
```

The  **"print "{0}".format(path1)"** is printing correct path but I am not able to get that value in perl. 
How can I store the path value in the variable in perl??

Answer (score 4):

The Perl built-in [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) returns the return value of the program, not the STDOUT. You need to use [`qx()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html).

```
my $path= qx(C:\\FindPath\\find_path_location.py $ID);
```

Be careful though, you cannot give multiple arguments to `qx`, as it's an *operator*, not a *function*.